# How to find the highest Value with Python

Tags: python

I have some variable values and it's changing like

I get these values

```
a = 0
b = 2
c = 4
d = 0

print (c)
```

how can I print the highest value like above and below

```
a = 6
b = 0
c = 5
d = 0

print (a)
```

please let me know how I can get the highest value with the python

thank you

Comment: You can use `max` builtin and pass the values/variables `max(a,b,c,d)`

Comment: Pack the variables (or the numbers directly) into a list or tuple and use function "max" on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to group all values in a container, such as a list, so you can manipulate them as one object, the list. Then use the `max` function

```
values = [a, b, c, d]
print(max(values))
```

Note that `max` also accepts multiple values directly

```
print(max(a, b, c, d))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Python program to find largest
# number in a list

# list of numbers
list1 = [10, 20, 4, 45, 99]


# printing the maximum element
print("Largest element is:", max(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
import heapq


arr = [10, 324, 45, 90, 9808,11]

# method 1
max_number = arr[0]

for ele in arr:
    if ele > max_number:
        max_number = ele

print("max number is", max_number)



# method 2
lis = [10, 324, 45, 90, 9808,11]
lis.sort(reverse=True)
print("max number is", lis[0])



#method 3
print("max number is", max(arr))



# method 4
max_num = reduce(max,arr)
print("max number is", max_num)


# method 5
max_num1 = reduce(lambda x,y:x if x>y else y,arr)
print("max number is", max_num)

# method 6
max_num2 = heapq.nlargest(1,arr)
print("max number is", max_num2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).